# Convert Set of Parent to List of Child using Java 8 streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

So I am trying to convert Set of Parent to List of Child using Java 8 streams.

Here is the parent class:

```
public class Parent<T extends GenericModel> {
    private String href;
    private String rel;
    private String title;
    private ResourceStatus status;
    private Parent source;
}
```

And here is the Child class:

```java
public class Child extends Parent<SomeClass> {
    private String category;
    private String type;
}
```

Now I already have `Set<Parent<SomeClass>>` which I want to convert to a `List<Child>`. I don't want to go the primitive way, but instead use Java 8 streams to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the elements in the `Set<Parent>` guaranteed to be all `Child` instances?

Comment: @Holger : yes  `Set<Parent>` gauranteed to be all  `Child` instance

Comment: can you show what fields you need in child ? and what you had in parent ?

Comment: @Deadpool: Child has 2 extra fields of type String. While Parent has these 5 fields:                               `private String href;
    private String rel;
    private String title;
    private ResourceStatus status;
    private Parent source;`

Comment: can you update the post with code, and with sample input and expected output @Kusum

Comment: Then, the fields are entirely irrelevant. You have an answer using a Stream variant but just consider “the primitive way” of a simple checked copy operation like `List<Child> listOfChild = Arrays.asList(setOfParent.toArray(new Child[0]));` It only works when all elements are of type `Child`, but then, it’s the simplest and most efficient variant…

Answer (score 1):

You can just stream and cast. If you're certain that they're of the right type then you can remove the filter at the risk of class cast exceptions.

Often exceptions are better than silently ignoring problems with your assumptions, but I'll leave it up to you to decide which is better for your case.

```
final List<Child> children = parents.stream()
    .filter(Child.class::isInstance)  //optional 
    .map(Child.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```